# Web scraping in apple swift 3

Tags: swift3, swift-playground

I'm a Swift beginner and I'm trying to figure out how to retrieve text from a web article, create a new text file and save the text data into it (Using Swift Playgrounds). Is this possible?

The only thing I could find online regarding the subject was this, and I don't think it is even written for Swift 3:

P.S. If my question needs more details, please let me know instead of putting it on hold. Thanks!

```
import Cocoa

var url = NSURL(string: "http://finance.yahoo.com/news/tv-news-ces-2017-120931816.html")

if url != nil {

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

        print(data)

        if error == nil {

            var urlContent = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as NSString!

            print(urlContent)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's Swift 2.3. In Swift 3 use `URL` instead of `NSURL` and use `URLSession` rather than `NSURLSession`, etc. You'd also use `String` rather than `NSString`. E.g.

```
let url = URL(string: "http://finance.yahoo.com/news/tv-news-ces-2017-120931816.html")!

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
    guard let data = data, error == nil else {
        print("\(error)")
        return
    }

    let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)

    print("\(string)")
}

task.resume()
```

If you're going to do this in a playground, remember that this runs asynchronously, so you'll need to set `needsIndefiniteExecution`.

```
import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

To actually parse the HTML, you should consider using a HTML parser like [TFHpple](https://github.com/topfunky/hpple) (written in Objective-C, but still works great from Swift) or [NDHpple](https://github.com/ndavon/NDHpple) (a Swift version, in which I don't have as much confidence as TFHpple, but probably would work fine).

You might want to see [How to Parse HTML on iOS](https://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios). It's dated, but walks you through the concepts (making sure you're not violating ToS of the web site, how to use the parsers, etc.).

---

If you want to save this to a file, you can do something like:

```
let fileURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
    .appendingPathComponent("test.dat")
try! data.write(to: fileURL)
```

You can use whatever file extension you want.

Comment: For some websites it returns nil. Why would this be?

Comment: Also, is it possible to write the data to a new textEdit file? Thanks!

Comment: It could be `nil` if it's not valid UTF8 (either designed to use another encoding, accidentally has non UTF8 character, or, most likely, they've deliberated added a non-UTF8 character in the page to thwart noobs from scraping it). You could certainly manually scan through and fix/remove the offending character before proceeding with the parsing. But I bet the page that is exhibiting this behavior is on that also has a terms of service that forbids scraping (many commercial sites do), so you may want to check that. Re saving, see revised answer.